# Need help to recreate a guessing game with while loops and other loops using java

Tags: java

Ok I need help on a school assignment that I'm currently stuck on and I need a lot of help. I have tried to do this for hours and still cant figure out on how to do this assignment. This is my code below.

I'm trying to create a guessing game. What I'm stuck on is how I'm suppose to loop the number of  10 guesses and no more. I tried it and it gives me an infinite loop.

What im trying to create:

- A number from 1 and 100 is picked and the player does not know what the number is.
- The player is asked to guess a number from 1 to 100.
- They have 10 chances to guess the right number.
- If the player does not guess the correct number within 10 guesses then the player loses the game.
- You let them know if their guess is too low or too high to help them narrow down their guesses to eventually guess the right number before their 10 guesses are used up.

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.util.Random;

  public class GuessGame3
  {
    public static void main (String[] args){

      int num1;
      int count=0;
      int Guess=0;

      Random generator = new Random();
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      //get generator
      num1 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;


      while (Guess != num1){
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100");

        Guess = scan.nextInt();
        count++;

        while (count > 10)
          System.out.println("Sorry you didnt guess in 10 trues its been " + count + " tries");

        if ( Guess > num1)
        {
          System.out.println("Lower!");
        }
        else if (Guess < num1)
        {
          System.out.println("Higher");
        }
        else
          System.out.println("Congratz with " + count + " amount of tries");
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: You never modify `count` in the loop `while (count > 10)` so once it is entered it will never be exited

Comment: I dont get what you saying sorry, do you mean that i dont put count > 10 in the while statement?

Comment: Really, the `while (count > 10)` should be `if (count > 10)`; otherwise it will just print "Sorry..." forever.

Comment: You don't need a nested while loop. Instead put `if(count > 10) {break;}`

Comment: oh sorry, ok thank you that worked, also i have another question , how would i ask the user to play again using a while loop? would i have to place it before my other while loop?

Comment: in the `if(count>10)` you can ask user want to play again or not, and proceed next @Bob.Bob

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting the checks if the guess is as part of the first while loop, not a nested one.:

```
while (count < 10){
System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100");
            Guess = scan.nextInt();
count++;
     if ( Guess > num1)
    {
        System.out.println("Lower!");
    }
    else if (Guess < num1)
    {
        System.out.println("Higher");
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
if(count < 10) {
    System.out.println("Congrats! You have completed it in " + count + " tries!");
} else {
    System.out.println("Sorry you have run out of your 10 guesses!");
}
```

There might be some errors here, but you should get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies with the loop and in the order you have validated the total number of tries and the Guess match. Try the below

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class TestGame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int num1;
    int count = 0;
    int Guess = 0;
    int maxAllowedRetries = 10;

    Random generator = new Random();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get generator
    num1 = generator.nextInt(100) + 1;
    while(count <= maxAllowedRetries)
    {
        if(count == maxAllowedRetries)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry you have reached maximum number of retries!");
            break;
        }
        count++;
        System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 100");
        Guess = scan.nextInt();
        if(Guess == num1)
        {
            System.out.println("Great you got it Right!");
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Sorry you didnt guess right. Its been " + count + " tries");

        if(Guess > num1)
        {
            System.out.println("Lower!");
        }
        else if(Guess < num1)
        {
            System.out.println("Higher");
        }
     }
  }
}
```